# State switching delayed? Do angular or ui-router wait for arbitrary $http promises to finish?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a controller, which calls a factory that performs $http requests. They are not in a ui-router resolve.

I've noticed a behavior which I consider strange - ui-router would not switch states while these requests are still in-transit. I understand how this makes sense with resolves, but why would it happen with arbitrary $http requests?

I'm using the newish `reloadOnSearch: false` feature, I thought it was worth mentioning

Comment: do you have any working examples of this behavior that you can provide for troubleshooting?

Comment: I'm looking for general knowledge about this, I don't even know if it's supposed to work like that. For all I know there's a setting somewhere :)

Comment: from your description, what you are suggesting is occurring should not be happening.  However, without code to verify your setup and identify the entire chain of events, it's not really possible to know if there is a step in the cycle that you are missing.